# Concatenating a dictionary of dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operating-system, concatenation

I looped through a folder of excel files, converted them to dataframes and put those dataframes into a dictionary where the keys are the file names. What I want to do is make this one large dataframe where the file names don't matter, since the column names of the data that I need are unique. I want to merge the 'Genes' column since they repeat, fill the NaN scores w/ zeros, and drop the 'Ratio' columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

folder = r'C:\Users\camer\Desktop\Stack Overflow' # Folder path
files = os.listdir(folder) 

dict1 = {}
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df1 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file))
        dict1[file] = df1

# Putting all excel files from file into dataframes, then setting those dataframes as the values in the preallocated dict,
# where the keys are the file names

df1 = pd.concat(dict1, axis=1)
df1
```

[image: df w/ file names]

If I try to group the gene columns while the dataframe is still separated by the filenames I get this:

```
df1 = pd.concat(dict1, axis=1)
df1 = df1.groupby(df1.columns, axis=1).sum()
df1
```

[image: df grouped by genes]

Comment: `pd.concat(dict1.values(),sort=False).groupby('Genes').sum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
pd.concat(dict1.values())
```